# JavaScript Promise and the this keyword

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given the following JS, how do I set the `message` property of the `PlateCheck` object?

```
var plateCheck = {
        plateNumber: '',
        message: '',
        alertClass: '',
        checkPlate: function (plateNumber) {
            PlateCheckService.checkPlate(plateNumber).then(function (response) {
                var data = response.data;

                if (data.VehicleAtl !== null) {
                    this.message = "Hot!";
                    this.alertClass = 'alert-danger';
                } else {
                    this.message = "Plate #" + data.PlateNumber + " is clean.";
                    this.alertClass = 'alert-success';
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

**Edit**

`PlateCheckService.checkPlate(plateNumber)` returns a promise...

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to set the `message` property based on the response of the `checkPlate` function?

Comment: @CyrilPangilinan -Yes. Also would like to understand how to maybe extract that functionality into the service and return an object with the correct message, alert class, etc from the promise to the service and then to the controller. I am using Angular BTW.

Comment: Should `checkPlate` really be a property of the `plateCheck` object? I'm thinking that `checkPlate` should just be a function called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be just a scoping issue, but to return the same object by calling `plateCheck.checkPlate(fooPlateNumber)` maybe this will do the trick.

```
var plateCheck = {
        plateNumber: '',
        message: '',
        alertClass: '',
        checkPlate: function (plateNumber) {
            var me = this;
            PlateCheckService.checkPlate(plateNumber).then(function (response) {
                var data = response.data;
                me.plateNumber = plateNumber;
                if (data.VehicleAtl !== null) {
                    me.message = "Hot!";
                    me.alertClass = 'alert-danger';
                } else {
                    me.message = "Plate #" + data.PlateNumber + " is clean.";
                    me.alertClass = 'alert-success';
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

But maybe you could just extract the service function, to return a `plateCheck` object as such.

```
function checkPlate(plateNumber) {
    var plateCheck = {};
    plateCheck.plateNumber = plateNumber;
    PlateCheckService.checkPlate(plateNumber).then(function (response) {
        var data = response.data;
        if (data.VehicleAtl !== null) {
            plateCheck.message = "Hot!";
            plateCheck.alertClass = 'alert-danger';
        } else {
            plateCheck.message = "Plate #" + data.PlateNumber + " is clean.";
            plateCheck.alertClass = 'alert-success';
        }
    });
    return plateCheck;
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing the same thing; `var _this = this;` and use that variable to set properties on the object. +1 for the answer!! Thanks a bunch!